# jQuery addClass over html Tags

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to `addClass` over tags with jQuery...

For example: I have this

```
<h4>Any title</h4>
<p> Text intro </p>
```

I wanna add the Class over it's..

```
<div class="myClass">
  <h4>Any title</h4>
  <p> Text intro </p>
</div>
```

**UPD** Thank you all )

Comment: what did you tried?

Comment: check out this https://api.jquery.com/addclass/

Comment: I think you are looking for `jQuery.wrap` method!

Comment: @Raki no.. I want create div with class myClass over this tag's

Comment: @TriSTaR Does your input markup already wrapped with something ? Is there any pattern for it ?

Comment: @Rayon Thank you..  that's exactly what I wanted =))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('h4,p').wrapAll("<div class=myClass></div>")
```

```css
.myClass {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Any title</h4>
<p>Text intro</p>
```

Use [.wrapAll()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapall/)

> Description: Wrap an HTML structure around all elements in the set of matched elements.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like you want to wrap several elements in another element with a class. You'll want something like this:

```
$("h4,p").wrapAll( $("<div>").addClass("myClass") );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$( "div" ).addClass( "myClass" );
```

But you may want to have for specific div only. In that case you can use different [selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) like id, first node or so on.

[Read more here](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/)

Comment: I found what I wanted =) jQuery wrap )

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('p, div, span').addClass('myclass');
```

[Demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/66bw5u4h/10/)

Answer (score 0):

your question is not clear .. but you can add class to any HTML tag with below syntax:

```
$("tagname").addClass("classname");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to dynamically add the div, check [wrap](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) out. Add the "inner" class to your elements:

```
<h4 class="inner">Any title</h4>
<p class="inner"> Text intro </p>
```

Then in your script:

```
$(".inner").wrap("<div class='myClass'></div>");
```

The final result:

```
<div class="myClass">
  <h4>Any title</h4>
  <p> Text intro </p>
</div>
```